# API Proxying vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, proxy

The code is on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/vuejs-ProxyTable-Axios)

The following example [API Proxying During development](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html)

gives an example of a proxyTable

```
// config/index.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  dev: {
    proxyTable: {
      // proxy all requests starting with /api to jsonplaceholder
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

under which they say,

The above example will proxy the request /api/posts/1 to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1.

but clearly posts/1 is missing from the example.

Or should the /posts/1 be in the proxyTable or in the .vue file using axios like this,

```
 axios.get("api/posts/1")
```

so that a HTTP GET request which starts with api with proxy to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com and then append the rest of that url, which in this case is /posts/1 and so it actually proxies to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Is this correct?

----------EDIT FROM HERE DOWN------------

In my own case

```
// config/index.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  dev: {
    proxyTable: {
      // proxy all requests starting with /conn to http://localhost:8081
      '/conn': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8081',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/conn': ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
axios.get("/conn/api.php?action=read")
```

should proxy to,

```
http://localhost:8081/api.php?action=read
```

But I get a console error,

GET http://localhost:8080/conn/api.php?action=read 504 (Gateway Timeout)

Thanks

Comment: Don't concern yourself too much with the fact that `/posts/1` is missing. The idea here is that you should be able to rewrite just the beginning of the URL and have the rest of it still remain available. What's occurring is `target` selects the base URL, `pathRewrite` replaces the pattern with the value it's associated with--in this case it replaces `'/api'` with `''`, and everything else is left alone.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I added to the post for my own case. Doesn't seem to be rewritting the url correctly or at least I don't know why it won't connect to the db. If I run a php server only and place http://localhost:8080/api.php?action=read in the browser it displays json in the browser. But this doesn't work when I also run the dev server.

Comment: You say it should proxy to `http://localhost:8081/api.php?action=read` but your configuration has `target` set to `http://localhost:8080`. Note that the ports differ. Could this be related to your problem? In any case, you're just receiving a 504, suggesting that either you're not connecting to the correct host or the host is improperly configured and your connection is failing. I don't have experience with this sort of browser proxying, but it seems possible that the failure is in your specifying an incorrect `target`.

Comment: Actually that was a typo in the original post. I corrected it in my code and in the OP. Unfortunately I am still getting the same result. But good to know what it should be. There are quite a few threads where people are having problems with axios and proxyTables. Thanks again

Comment: @B.Fleming The strange thing for me is that I am able to connect to the host with http://localhost:8081/api.php?action=read if I only run the php server and not the 'npm run dev'.

Comment: Strange. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with `npm` or related tech, just vue.js and PHP, so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem. It could be that your proxy isn't set correctly for either vue or axios to work with it. I can't really say for certain. Good luck in any case!

Comment: Ok thanks for your help anyway.